# Why is my if statement unexpected?

Tags: python

So below is my code, I'm supposed to create a list that contains places in which should have a distance. The user should select two different places to view how far apart they are in miles, they are then given the option to convert into kilometres. However I sort of completed the code so it worked and I then went to add an if statement that should say something like "if the user enters place1, place2 or place 3 then continue onto asking the user to enter a second place otherwise restart the program back to the beginning. However the if statement isn't written correctly and it now says "Second isn't defined"

```
print 'The available places to select from are:'

print 'place1, place2, place3: '


place1 = 50
place2 = 40
place3 = 30
Convert = 1.609344



First = str(raw_input('Please select from the list where you are coming from'))
if raw_input == 'place1' 'place2' 'place3':
    Second = str(raw_input('Please select where you are going to: '))
else:
    print 'please press any key to restart'

Distance = First + Second

print "the distance between the two places are", Distance, "miles"



Kilometres = bool(input('Would you like to convert to Kilometres? please type True to convert or False to exit: '))
if True:
        print 'The distance in Kilometres is',First + Second / Convert, 'Kilometres'

else:
        print 'press any ket to terminate'
```

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory? It says your indentation at the `if` statement is incorrect. You should move the if-else block 4 spaces left.

Comment: Indentation is important - your `if`/`else` can't be indented

Comment: The other error is you're defining "Distance" before First and Second have been set.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, the reason I added the indent after I tried it without the indent was because it seemed as though the if statement wasn't taking affect, therefore I come to the conclusion that the if statement needed to be indented to show that it is apart of that section. Anyhow removing the indentation didn't work, if I type anything other than place1 place2 or place3 it just says placex isn't defined, which I know it isn't but it's supposed to print "please choose only place1, place2 or place3"  Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel You want to be using `raw_input` - `input` is something else entirely

Comment: Thanks Jon, I changed them all back to raw_input but I'm sure the last time I done that it wasn't outputting a literal value it was just saying "place1 + place2" but I've changed the code and now it's stating "Second is not defined" so I'm kind of baffled I'll update the code in the original question if you could have a look?

Comment: In general, guessing at syntax is an indication that it's time to go back and start studying the language docs rather than munging your code until it looks like it works. Guessing gets you into situations like this in languages that have at least moderately decent syntax checking (where you're asking not about your initial problems, but on additional ones you created while casting around) -- but in other languages (bash in particular) it'll get you things that _look_ like they work but are full of subtle bugs, which is far worse.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree to an extent but I'm not your typical "fail once give up and ask everyone" I've been reading my book and using other sources and I'm just not getting it, I've been trying for hours so this is the next best thing. The problem with Python is not all scenarios are the same which is the reason for noobies it becomes tedious, as I said I've researched and been reading continuously for hours but no example seems to involve what mine does and that's why I'm ending up experimenting.

Answer (score 7):

Don't indent your if statement.

```
First = int(input('Please select from the list where you are coming from'))
if answer in ['place1', 'place2', 'place3']:
    Second = int(input('Please select where you are going to: '))
else:
    print 'please press any key to restart'
```

instead of

```
First = int(input('Please select from the list where you are coming from'))
    if answer in ['place1', 'place2', 'place3']:
        Second = int(input('Please select where you are going to: '))
    else:
        print 'please press any key to restart'
```

Edit:

It seems you need some help with this.  I reworked your code and added some comments to hopefully clear things up.

```
#using a dictionary allows us to associate, or hash, a string with a value
place_dict = {"place1":50,"place2":40,"place3":30}

convert = 1.609344

def run_main():
    #placing the bulk of the program inside of a function allows for easy restarting
    print 'The available places to select from are:'
    print 'place1, place2, place3: '

    first = raw_input('Please select from the list where you are coming from: ')
    second = raw_input('Please select where you are going: ')
    #the values the user puts in are now stored in variables called 'first' and 'second', so if the user inputs "one", then first == "one"

    if first not in place_dict or second not in place_dict:
        #check to ensure that both first and second are in the place place dictionary
        #if not, then return none to the main program
        raw_input('Press any key to restart...')
        return None

    #an else is not needed here, because if the if statement executes, then we will not reach this point in the program

    #this returns the dictionary value of the first value that the user inputs + the second.
    return place_dict[first] + place_dict[second]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #this line says that if we are running the program, then to execute.  This is to guard against unwanted behavior when importing

    distance = None
    #set an initial variable to None

    while distance is None:
        #run the main program until we get an actual value for distance
        distance = run_main()

    print "the distance between the two places are", distance, "miles"


    kilometres = bool(input('Would you like to convert to Kilometres? please type True to convert or False to exit: '))
    if kilometres == True:
        print 'The distance in Kilometres is',distance / convert, 'Kilometres'

    else:
        print 'press any key to terminate'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did try this however it seemed as though when I did this the if statement wasn't functioning correctly. For example I remove then indentations and then deliberately type something other than place1 or place2 or place3 but rather than outputting the else statement it just crashes and outputs place5 isn't defined. Which I know it isn't defined but it's supposed to print what's in my else statement. Any ideas?

Comment: A few things...right now, you're else statement doesn't restart the program.  What happens is you hit the else statement, and then the code keeps executing, it doesn't restart.  You could use a function to fix this.
Second, you're storing the value being taken as First, but then accessing is as answer (if answer in... should be if First in).
Third, you're casting your input for First as an int, but then comparing it to strings.  You shouldn't need to cast it.

Comment: Sorry Schiem that sort of baffled me, I can understand how the else statement wouldn't restart the program, but as for problem two I'm not quite sure how to rectify this :/ and yes as for the third this was all I could think of doing, I know when it was shown a while ago they made a list that contained a place name with a number which was to represent the distance, however I couldn't remember how they done that so off the top of my head & trying to use a few different sources I couldn't find an example where someone creates a list using a string thats associated with the literal.